# JQuery Select Tag

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to put an input text here in my select tag using Jquery please. I am not good at this, that's why I'm sorry. I'll also put my script code and can you tell me where can I put it. Sorry.

User input fields are located in index.php, and I used jquery and ajax to pass it to my php file. I was wondering if I could have an option in my select tag wherein users can input (like an Others field). And how would it change my jquery code. Thank you.

INDEX.PHP

```
<!--DOCUMENT INPUT-->
        <div class="row space3" >
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="code" id="code" class="form-control" placeholder="Document Code" /> 
            </div>
            **<div class="col-sm-2">
                <select name="doc_kind" id="doc_kind" class="form-control" placeholder="Document Kind">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Kind of Document</option>
                    <option value="Budget Proposal">Budget Proposal</option>
                    <option value="Project Proposal">Project Proposal</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>**

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="datetime-local" name="date_submitted" id="date_submitted" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Submitted" style="width:120%;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <textarea name="remarks" id="remarks" class="form-control" placeholder="Remarks" style="margin-left: 12%" rows="1"></textarea>
            </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="docu_id" style="margin-left: 12%" />
                        <button class="button add" name="action" id="action">Add</button>
                </div>
                <br><br>
        </div>
<!--END OF DOCUMENT INPUT-->
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
    function fetchDocu() {
        var action = "select";
        $.ajax({
            url: "select.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                action: action
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#code').val('');
                $('#doc_kind').val('');
                $('#date_submitted').val('');
                $('#remarks').val('');
                $('#action').text("Add");
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#action').click(function () {
        var docCode = $('#code').val();
        var docKind = $('#doc_kind').val();
        var dateSubmitted = $('#date_submitted').val();
        var docRemarks = $('#remarks').val();
        var docNote = $('#note').val();
        var id = $('#docu_id').val();
        var action = $('#action').text();
        if (docCode != '' && docKind != '' && dateSubmitted != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    docCode: docCode,
                    docKind: docKind,
                    dateSubmitted: dateSubmitted,
                    docRemarks: docRemarks,
                    id: id,
                    action: action
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    fetchDocu();
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! welcome to stackoverflow. From the way you phrased the question it will be difficult for you to get a good answer, You just pasted some script, but it is not clear what you need to achieve exactly.

Comment: Could you please tell exact requirement we may suggest alternative solution

Comment: It sounds like OP wants an input element within their select element. Im guessing something like autocomplete? OP can you please confirm what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited the content of my question, sorry I am new here

Comment: @Sagar I need to have an "others" option wherein users can input their own option.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to.do it on select tag but from your above queation your requirement is unclear

Comment: I see. Can you suggest on how should I do it? I want to have an "others" option in my select tag so that if a user's option is not listed they will be able to click others and input their own option.

Comment: have u tried a jquery plugin called select 2???
It will work magic for your requirement.. I am sure about it

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you!

Comment: if u cant seem to work it out after research please tell me..i might create a post on my blog bout it

Comment: I was able to find it but it's not what I am looking for (sort of), but please do. It would a big help.

Comment: please give me a detail requirement on what you want before i provide u the answer

Comment: So, I have a list of documents in a select tag. Now, of course I just cannot put all the kinds of documents, so I want to put an Others. Now, if a user clicked on Others, I want them to able to specify what kind of document is that it.

Think of a survey questionnaire. There is an Others (pls. specify):_____

I hope I was able to explain it well

Comment: I have an alternative to solve your question using select 2.  Can I teach you in chat anywhere???


[link] http://prntscr.com/im7p7f [/link]

[link] http://prntscr.com/im7php [/link]

please check these images

Comment: That would be great. Where do you suggest we can have the chat?